# Golang html/templates : ParseFiles with custom Delims

Tags: angularjs, templates, go

Using templates with delimiters works fine when using `template.New("...").Delims("[[", "]]").Parse()`
However, I cannot figure out how to get to the same result with `template.ParseFiles()`

```
tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("base.tmpl", "homepage/inner.tmpl")
if err != nil { panic(err) }
tmpl.Delims("[[", "]]")
p := new(Page) 
err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, p)
if err != nil { panic(err) }
```

I have no errors, but the Delimiters are not changed.

```
tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("base.tmpl", "homepage/inner.tmpl")
t := tmpl.Lookup("base.tmpl").Delims("[[", "]]")
p := new(Page) 
err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, p)
if err != nil { panic(err) }
```

This leads to the same result.

In case this is relevant, my need is to embed a small angular app in a particular page of my site.

Also, I have a base template with a common HTML structure that I combine with a page-specific template with ParseFiles(), leading to this layout :

```
/templates/base.tmpl
/templates/homepage/inner.tmpl
/templates/otherpage/inner.tmpl
```

Is this possible at all ? If so, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It looks like you should be able to do `template.New(...).Delims(...).ParseFiles(...)` from [the docs](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ParseFiles). This is the second ParseFiles in the index, not the first.

Comment: Indeed ! Even though I've worked on this for quite some time, I figured this out a few moments after posting the question. I find it hard to wrap my head around this package :) Thanks for your help !

Comment: For future readers, another detail I was lacking is that I needed to always name the template "base.tmpl" for any page by using template.New("base.tmpl"). I guess that's because it is the name of the root template to use among the parsed template set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a dummy template, set the delimiters and then parse the files:

```
 tmpl, err := template.New("").Delims("[[", "]]").ParseFiles("base.tmpl", "homepage/inner.tmpl")
```

This aspect of the API is quirky and not very obvious. The API made more sense in the early days when the template package had the additional Set type

Comment: Note for others: Blank "" argument for template.New() caused runtime panic for me. Replace template.New("") with template.New("some_template_name")

Comment: Not only what @codefreak said but you also have to call ExecuteTemplate with the name given as well.  Calling just Execute will give you a nil pointer dereference panic.